# REACT: Erro ao chamar Dados da API

Tags: react, api, axios, react-router

Meu site tem apenas duas páginas a **Home** (onde aparece todos os pokemons) e a **detalhes** onde aparece os detalhes do Pokemon.

A primeira página carrega normal, já a página de detalhes do pokemon dá um erro quando a página abre.
OBS.... se eu não "puxar" a imagem e os status do pokemon a página abre

[print do erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsv3C.png)

```
import './detalhes.css';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

// import axios from 'axios';
import api from '../../Services/api';


function Detalhes(){

    const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const { id } = useParams();
    

  

    useEffect(() => {
        async function LoadDetalhes() {
            const response = await api.get(`pokemon/${id}` , {
                params: {
                    id: id,
                } 
            })
            setPokemon(response.data)
            setLoading(false)
        }
        
        LoadDetalhes()

        }, [])


        if(loading){
            (
                <h2>Carregando...</h2>
            )
        }
        
    return(
        <div className='container-detalhes'>
            <div  className='card-detalhes'>
                <h1>Detalhes do Pokemon {pokemon.name}</h1>
                <strong>{pokemon.name}</strong>
                 <img src={pokemon.sprites.front_default} alt={pokemon.name}></img> 

                 <div className='status'>
                    <div>
                    <strong>{pokemon.stats[0].stat.name} = {pokemon.stats[0].base_stat}</strong><br></br>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                    <strong>{pokemon.stats[1].stat.name} = {pokemon.stats[1].base_stat}</strong><br></br>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                    <strong>{pokemon.stats[2].stat.name} = {pokemon.stats[2].base_stat}</strong><br></br>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                    <strong>{pokemon.stats[3].stat.name} = {pokemon.stats[3].base_stat}</strong><br></br>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                    <strong>{pokemon.stats[4].stat.name} = {pokemon.stats[4].base_stat}</strong><br></br>
                    </div>


                    <div>
                    <strong>{pokemon.stats[5].stat.name} = {pokemon.stats[5].base_stat}</strong><br></br>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                    <strong>{pokemon.types.type[0].name}</strong> 
                    </div>
                </div>
               
                
               
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Detalhes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olhando o erro, ele ocorre na declaração do JSX onde você vai mostrar a imagem do pokemon, pois ele tenta acessar o atributo *front_default* dentro do atributo *sprites* que está sem valor definido.

```
<img src={pokemon.sprites.front_default} alt={pokemon.name}></img>
```

Coloque um debugger na linha `setLoading(false)` e veja se o atributo *sprites* está com valor dentro do objeto do state *pokemon*.

Comment: o estranho é que tem este atributo, "uso o mesmo na página inicial", o estranho é que as vezes ele carrega a image, e as vezes não. (serve para outros dados tb)

Comment: Testa com outros pokemon se dá o mesmo erro. Talvez tenha algum sem essa informação

Comment: com todos é a mesma coisa.... as vezes carrega a imagem e outras vezes não.... fiz o teste no console.log e mesma coisa..... uma suspeita que eu tive foi se quando estava chamando a API talvez algum dado não estava vindo por causa  de algum limite ou algo assim

Comment: Uma sugestão seria fazer o acesso aos sub atributos de forma de segura usando a lib lodash: `<img src={_.get(pokemon, 'sprites.front_default') )} alt={_.get(pokemon, 'name')} />`

Fiz uma edição aqui para você testar: [código](https://gist.github.com/adrianoxavier/a43e80768ce64e1f3348798c054e1890)

Comment: Finalmente Funcionou... só vou precisar entender como funciona essa biblioteca para usar futuramente.... MUITO OBRIGADO